# Getting sum out of an input array's elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple rows in a table that look like this.

```
<tr>
<td>Item 1</td>
<td><input type=TEXT name="item_name[]"  /></td>
<td><input type=TEXT name="item_desc[]"  /></td>
<td><input type=TEXT name="item_type[]"  /></td>
<td><input type=TEXT name="item_price[]" /></td>
<td><input type=TEXT name="item_setup[]" /></td>
<td><input type=TEXT name="item_quant[]" /></td>
</tr>
```

etc...

Users can dynamically add more rows or delete them.

I'm trying to do the JS part that will display the total sum of all item_price*item_quant and display it inside of this bit on keyup or blur or change.

```
<tr><td id=total></td></tr>
```

EDIT: tried the following so far. added an "onblur" to each field that calls updateTotal() below:

```
function updateTotal() {
var total = 0; 

$("input[id^='item_quant[']").each(function() {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        total += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
});

$("#total").val(total);
}
```

but still no go

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: Show what you tried, please.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('table').on('change', 'input[name="item_price[]"], input[name="item_quant[]"]', function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('table').find('tr').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var amount = (parseFloat($this.find('input[name="item_price[]"]').val(), 10) || 0)
        * (parseFloat($this.find('input[name="item_quant[]"]').val(), 10) || 0);
        total += amount;
    })

    $('#total').text(total)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/69Xcd/)

Comment: This seems very promising. It works on its own, but when i put into my page, it breaks. Wondering if it's because i have other tables in there. How would i go about making this work only for the table that has the items in it?

Comment: @user2720050 add a id to the target table and use it... like if the table id is `my-table` then change `$('table')` to `$('#my-table')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by converting each element value into integer and then perform sum math.

**Example**

```
var add = 0;
$("input").each(function()
{
     add += Number($(this).val());//for integer
     //add += parseFloat($(this).val());//for float or decimal
});
$("#total").html("Sum of all textboxes is : " + add);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".txt").each(function () {

         //add only if the value is number
         if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
             sum += parseFloat(this.value);
         }

     });
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/69Xcd/6/)**

Comment: not quite what i want to do. need to have array fields as they are dynamic and can be added on the fly. and i also need to be able to multiply the quanitty by the price.